# Printing two pyramids side by side (ASCII graphics)

Tags: c

I am able to crack it up till @symbol but not after that.

I am not aware of logic for implementing two pyramids side by side.

```
int main()
    {
        int i, space, n, j, l, k=0;

        printf("Enter number excluding 1 and -ve numbers: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        for(i=1; i<=n-1; ++i, k=0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<(n/2);j++)
            {
                printf("\t");
            }
            for(space=1; space<=n-i; ++space)
            {
                printf("  ");
            }

            while(k != 2*i-1)
            {
                printf("* ");
                ++k;
            }//End of upper star pyramid 
            printf("\n");
        }

       //logic for @
        for(j=1;j<=(n-1);j++)
            {
                  for(l=0;l<(n/2);l++)
                {
                    printf("\t");
                }
                for(l=1; l<space; ++l)
                {
                    printf("  ");
                }
                printf("@");
                for(l=1; l<=n; l++)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("@\n");
            }
        //after that I dont know how to work with two different pyramids side by side
        return 0;
    }
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: `I am able to crack it uptill` - post your code. Please don't post images of text, the images don't get indexed by the search engine on this site. If you can, please use proper formatting styles and post text as text.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have now added my code.

Comment: "I am not aware of the logic for implementing two pyramids side by side." They are almost the same as the pyramid at the top. There are up to `n` stars on each side of the bottom of figure. So until that point, output `n` spaces on each line. Then start printing stars and/or spaces.

Comment: Aside about `i<=n-1;` This is harder to read than `i < n;` and in some cases is *wrong*.

Comment: I suggest to use spaces instead of tabulators (`'\t'`). Your code prints spaces between subsequent asterisks, e.g. `* * *` instead of `***`. Is this intentional? It would be better to show the user input and expected output **as text** (output formatted as a code block) in the question instead of using images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt...

Have used "#define"s for the characters to be printed.

Have utilized three do-while loops to break the task of printing the top pyramid, the "@"s and the bottom pyramid.

The solution would work for the examples provided or any "Odd" number, provided by the user.

For even numbers,the solution needs to be worked upon(either ways the top of the pyramid would not align at the center for even numbers).

Hope this is helpful.....feel free to play around with the code....

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SPACE ' '
#define STAR '*'
#define AT '@'


int main(){

  int num = 7;//input from the user, have used 7 as an example

  int total_hor_length = num * 3;//# of characters to be printed on each line
  int i = num;
  int j = 0;
  while(i > 0){//calculate the iterations
    j++;        //required for top and bottom
    i -= 2;     //Pyramids
  }
  int first_print = j; //# first loop iteration
  int last_print = first_print; //# last loop iteration
  int center_print = (num * 2 - 1)-(first_print + last_print);//# center loop
  int pos = total_hor_length/2; //position of top of center pyramid
  int count = 0;
  int k;


  i = 0;//re-initialize i for the first loop 
  //Logic for the Top Pyramid(first loop)
  do{
    for(k = 0;k < total_hor_length;++k){ //for input "n"
      if((k < pos || k > pos+count))     //by the time this loop finishes
        printf("%c",SPACE);              //pos will be "n-1"
      else                               //and count will be "n+1"
        printf("%c",STAR);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    pos--;
    count+=2;
    i++;
  }while( first_print > i);

 i = 0;//re-initialize i for the center loop 
 //Logic for the "@"s (second loop)
 do{
   for(k = 0;k < total_hor_length;++k){       //utilizing the values of "count"
     if((k == count-1 || k == (count-1)+pos)) //and pos procured from the previous 
       printf("%c",AT);                       //loop to print the "@"s
     else
       printf("%c",SPACE);
   }
   putchar('\n');
   i++;
 }while(center_print > i);

 i = 0;//re-initialize i for the center loop 
 //Logic for the Bottom Pyramids (Last loop)
 do{
   for(k = 0;k < total_hor_length;++k){                                   
     if(i == 0){
       if((k <= pos-i) || (k > pos + num + i && k < total_hor_length - i))
         printf("%c",STAR);
       else if(k == pos+1||k == pos+num) //printing the line containing
         printf("%c",AT);                // asterisk and "@" symbols
       else
         printf("%c",SPACE);
     }
    else{
      if((k >= i && k <= pos-i) || (k > pos + num + i && k < total_hor_length - i))
       printf("%c",STAR);    //printing the last lines
      else
       printf("%c",SPACE);
    }
  }
     putchar('\n');
     i++;
 }while(i < last_print);

}
```